# javascript toggle visibility and add function preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html

i´m trying to display popup-divs within a site and it works quite well, except for one thing –
i want to prevent the Default behavior of refreshing the site. I´m new to javascript and i honestly don´t know how to add the function (i already found the right one, i think...).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleVisibility(selectedPopup) {

     var popvar = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');

     for(var i=0; i<popvar.length; i++) {
          if(popvar[i].id == selectedPopup) {
                popvar[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
          } else {
                popvar[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
     }

}
```

It works like i wanted it to work – it displays the selected DIV, hides the other and vice versa. 
Still, i want to prevent the site from jumping to the top. So i added this snippet:

```
$(function() {
    $("#").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

The responding html is this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('pop01');">
```

and this

```
<div id="pop01" class="popup">
    <img src="assets/img/01/01_02_pop_01.png"></img>
</div>
```

How can i include the second javascript snippet into the first one?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: try `<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('pop01'); return false;">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to pass `event` into your function.

**The HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility(event, 'pop01');">
```

**The Javascript (partial)**

```
function toggleVisibility(event, selectedPopup) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var popvar = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
   // etc...
}
```

I believe that should do it!

**JSFiddle Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/c4LXf/

Comment: Many thanks drew_w, that did it! And, as a bonus – i think i´ve learned something about syntax! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can just remove the `#` and replace with `javascript:;`

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggleVisibility('pop01');">
```

Or remove the onclick and just use the href:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleVisibility('pop01');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(function() {
  $("#").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

try

```
$(function() {
  $("#").click(function(event){
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return toggleVisibility('pop01');">
```

If you add a `return false` in your function:

```
function toggleVisibility(selectedPopup) {

     // your code ...

     return false;
}
```

Or, Change your link like:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleVisibility('pop01');">
```